# ASP.NET string not printing to tdInnerHtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick, innerhtml

Software: Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition
Book: `Programming ASP.NET 3.5` by O'Reilly

Here is a table

[image]

This is the markup. Note that tdInnerHtml is on last column, last row

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                City</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                State</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                </td>
            <td class="style2">
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td id="tdInnerHtml" runat="server">
               &nbsp;  </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" onServerClick="Button1_OnServerClick" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

This is the action when Button1 is clicked

```
protected void Button1_OnServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string strHtml = "";
    strHtml += txtName.Text + "<br/>";
    strHtml += txtStreet.Text+ "<br/>";
    strHtml += txtCity.Text + ", " + txtState.Text;
    tdInnerHtml.InnerHtml = strHtml;
}
```

When I run program and press Button, nothing is written to the screen

[image]

Comment: change onServerClick to OnClick and define a label inside <td> tdInnerHtml and write your output to that label.

Comment: put a break point at your event handler and check if it is hit when you click the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attribuing the wrong attribute on your button for the `OnClick` event.

Try to change `onServerClick` to `OnClick` like this:

```
<asp:button runat="server" ID="button1" OnClick="Button1_OnServerClick" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! The book said `onServerClick`

Comment: Don't forget to tag this as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the attribute `onServerClick to onClick`. As you already got the answer the ***explaination*** is like

`OnServerClick` invokes the `ServerClick` Event of the button, meaning it causes a round trip to the server before executing your event handler. `onclick` is executed on the client-side, such as with Javascript

The `OnServerClick` isn't fired until the round trip to the server is complete, the onclick (client-side) will always fire first..